# SpringBoot with React - Rest API clashes with React Routes on refresh

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, react-router

I am working on Spring Boot and React.

I am exposing some REST APIs that will be consumed by the React app.

In React I have user route

Something like this

```
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>           
            <PrivateRoute path="/profile" authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
              component={Profile}></PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/login"
              render={(props) => <Login authenticated={this.state.authenticated} {...props} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/signup"
              render={(props) => <Signup authenticated={this.state.authenticated} {...props} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/oauth2/redirect" component={OAuth2RedirectHandler}></Route>  
            <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
          </Switch>
```

Endpoints:

```
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/signup
http://localhost:3000/dashboard
```

I have bundled both React and Spring Boot by adding these line in `pom.xml`  to run on a single port 8080

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>authserver-react</workingDirectory>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
                        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/authserver-react/build" />
                    </copy>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Once done I run build and `mvn spring-boot:run`  and open browser at `http://localhost:8080`

React comes in picture and redirect to `http://localhost:8080/login`

The problem is if I refresh the Page by clicking refresh button, Spring throws Whitelabel Error Page.

This is happening because I have not defined any Controller with "/login". But I don't want to define that.

Now I am not sure how do I differentiate React route with Spring APIs.

I don't want to run React in a different port and Spring Boot in a different port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I got it right. It was just a matter of understanding the flow.

`antrun` is configured in `pom.xml` to copy my react `/build` files to Spring's `/static` folder.

This means my react's `index` file will we residing in the static folder.

I only had to write a controller which resolves my react routes to index.

Something like this

```
@Controller
public class TemplateFile
{

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login", "/dashboard", "/signup" })
    public String HomePage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Now my code works fine with spring port i.e

```
http://localhost:8080/login
http://localhost:8080/signup
http://localhost:8080/dashboard
```

**Note:** I still need to optimize the controller class with some regex.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me. But how do I configure routes with query params? For eg. /dashboard/1.
I tried "/dashboard/{id}" and "/dashboard/:id".